# How to implement a class constant static fields declarations with dependency injection pattern

Tags: java, dependency-injection, static, constants, guice

I am learning dependency injection with Guice. I'm trying to understand if there is a recommended way to implement static class constants when programming with a dependency injection framework.

Huracan class first version:

```
public class Huracan implements Car {
    public static final URL COMPANY_URL;
    public static final String CAR_TYPE = "sports car";

    static {
        try {
            COMPANY_URL = new URL("www.lamborghini.com");   

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }   

    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Lamborghini Huracan " + CAR_TYPE + " driving!" );
    }
}
```

I can create a module - HuracanModule - and there I can use bindConstant and bind toInstance for the binding and remove the static constants declarations from the Huracan class.

Guice Huracan module:

```
public class HuracanModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("cars.huracan.cartype")).to("sports car");
        bind(URL.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("cars.huracan.company_url")).
          toInstance(new URL("www.lamborghini.com"));
    }   
}
```

Huracan class second version:

```
public class Huracan implements Car {           
    private final String CAR_TYPE;
    private final URL COMPANY_URL;

    public Huracan( @Named("cars.huracan.cartype") String carType, 
                    @Named("cars.huracan.comany_url") URL companyUrl ) {
            this.CAR_TYPE = carType;
            this.COMPANY_URL = companyUrl;
    }

    public void drive() {
            System.out.println("Lamborghini Huracan " + CAR_TYPE + " driving!" );
    }
}
```

I understand that this gives you the flexibility to manipulate the constants in different scenarios. But I am feeling I am missing something.

- Is this the right programming model ? Is there suppose to be a Guice model for every class you want to store static constants ? Or create only one giant main app module for everything ? What is the semantic correlation between a module and a class ?

With using static constants declaration on the class, the burden of knowing how to refer to them uniquely is handled by the programing language itself. ex. **Huracan.CAR_TYPE**. With dependency injection, I find that the annotation is needed to be unique. ex. **@Named("cars.huracan.cartype")**. It needs also to be unique globally if the module is to be combined with other modules to create the main app module. So in the end I find myself giving the string I put in the annotation, or the name for the custom annotation I create, the same meaning of the CLASS.FIELD structure.

- Is that correct ? But then I am losing the programing language "namespace" feature and I have to manually make sure every string key or annotation name is unique globally.

Any thoughts on the matter will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the right programming model ? Is there suppose to be a Guice model for every class you want to store static constants ? Or create only one giant main app module for everything ? What is the semantic correlation between a module and a class ?

Yes. :-)

It can go both ways.  With dependencies that are likely to be used only by one class, it makes sense to have a module just for that class, and install it at higher levels.  In other cases it will make more sense to bind certain constants at the highest level module, or even in separate common/shared modules.  Physically there is just one big module; logically how you lay it out will depend on both personal preference and the problem at hand, just like the architecture of any application code.

> But then I am losing the programing language "namespace" feature and I have to manually make sure every string key or annotation name is unique globally.

If you use a custom `@BindingAnnotation` for your annotations then you don't have to worry about namespace collisions anymore.  The [doc](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) on this even touches on the subject:

> *Since the compiler can't check the string, we recommend using* `@Named` *sparingly.*

Here's the alternate version:

```
public class Huracan implements Car {           
    private final String CAR_TYPE;
    private final URL COMPANY_URL;

    @BindingAnnotation
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface HuracanCar {}

    public Huracan( @HuracanCar String carType, 
                    @HuracanCar URL companyUrl ) {
        this.CAR_TYPE = carType;
        this.COMPANY_URL = companyUrl;
    }
}
```

And the module:

```
public class HuracanModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(String.class).annotatedWith(HuracanCar.class).to("sports car");
        bind(URL.class).annotatedWith(HuracanCar.class).
          toInstance(new URL("www.lamborghini.com"));
    }   
}
```

Note that I replaced your use of `bindConstant` with an explicit String binding.  I don't know enough about how `bindConstant` behaves to know if it would allow the duplicate usage of the same annotation as I am doing.  But I wanted to make a point that in general (at least when using explicit class binding as I am), not only does this version get you namespace safety, it also illustrates that you don't need separate names/annotations for each data type.  You can reuse `@Huracan` within the same module for a dozen different dependencies as long as each one is a different type.

Comment: Thank you ! I was investigating the same path, ended with inner annotation class with a value attribute so I can bind to different fields of the same type in the class. Much like "Named(String name)" is. Didn't like the String so I put an inner Enum the seperate the fields. But that required implementing a custom annotation implementation much like Guice NamedImpl which is a bit overkill :). I will choose this answer if no other magical one will be :)

Comment: Yes, ended up using separate annotation in the class for each data field I wanted to represent. Just a few lines. The custom annotation approach on the other hand, needed for each class to be written each time in it because of no way to do generics on the annotation interface.